# What are the disadvantages of using ANTLR compared to Flex/Bison?

Tags: antlr, bison, flex-lexer, jflex

I've worked on Flex, Bison few years ago during my undergraduate studies. However, I don't remember much about it now. Recently, I have come to hear about ANTLR.

- Would you recommend that I learn ANTLR or better to brush up Flex/Bison?
- Does ANTLR have more/less features than Flex/Bison?

Comment: The other way around [advantages-of-antlr-versus-say-lex-yacc-bison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212900/advantages-of-antlr-versus-say-lex-yacc-bison)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of Antlr (versus say, lex/yacc/bison)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212900/advantages-of-antlr-versus-say-lex-yacc-bison) @nawfal: Yeah.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ANTLRv3 is LL(k), and can be configured to be LL(*). The latter in particular is ridiculously easy to write parsers in, as you can essentially use EBNF as-is.

Also, ANTLR generates code that is quite a lot like recursive descent parser you'd write from scratch. It's very readable and easy to debug to see why the parse doesn't work, or works wrong.

The advantage of Flex/Bison (or any other LALR parser) is that it's faster.

Comment: Faster? Are you comparing LALR to LL(k) or LL(\*)? LL(k) parsing is quite fast. LL(\*) parsing is slow because of backtracking, but you rarely need to use it (and even when you do, I believe ANTLR lets you use LL(\*) for a subset of your grammar). The one advantage LALR has that I know of is that there are certain grammars that can't be parsed LL(k) that can be parsed LALR, but in practice most grammars that you'd actually *want* to parse can be re-expressed in a form that can be parsed LL(k).

Comment: Yes. LALR is faster because you can use a table-driven finite state machine for that. It's incomprehensible and nigh impossible to debug that once it's produced by a parser generator like Bison, but it's also very fast. LL(k) as implemented by ANTLR uses recursive descent parsing, which is somewhat slower.

Comment: I just tried the antlrworks tool and the following thing did not work:

expr : expr '+' expr;

because it does not allow left recursion. Don't you all find that a bit inconvenient. You have to then convert it to something like

expr : expr ('+' expr)*

i.e. write it like a regular expression. In flex I could write the former way and I found it much more natural than this regex style.

Comment: @ajay, that's the gist of the difference. For some constructs, writing them right-recursive is more natural. For others, writing them left-recursive is more natural. That said, for a simple grammar for something like `1 * (2 + 3) - 4` which your example suggests, you'd rather write something like: `expr: term ('+' | '-') expr; term: factor ('*' | '/') term; factor : literal_number | '(' expr ')'`. Which one is more natural is a matter of debate, but notice how ANTLR doesn't need any special construct for operator associativity - it's inherent in the grammar terms themselves.

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR has a run-time library JAR that you must include in your project.

ANTLR's recursive-descent parsers are easier to debug than the "bottom-up" parsers generated by Flex/Bison, but the grammar rules are slightly different.

If you want a Flex/Bison-style (LALR) parser generator for Java, look at [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

We have decided to use ANTLR for some of our information processing requirements - parsing legacy files and natural language. The learning curve is steep ut we are getting on top of it and I feel that it's a more modern and versatile approach for what we need to do. The disadvantages - since you ask - are mainly the learning curve which seems to be inevitable.

Comment: I suspect the learning curve for pretty much any parser generator is roughly the same. It only takes 5 minutes to "technically" understand the phrase "It is LALR..." or "It is LL..." It takes weeks to grok the machinery you have to use, to get a grammer wrangled into shape, to learn how to bend the grammar, ... All things being equal, the learning curves being similar, you should pick the most powerful parser generator that works in your world.