# Where to find a comparison of Flex/Bison, Ragel, ANTLR and others?

Tags: c, regex, osc

I am intending to define a protocol similar to [*Open Sound Control*](http://opensoundcontrol.org/), but a bit different.

The idea is quite complex, and I won't try to describe it here.

Suppose I was to implement an OSC library using libev and one of the tools in the *subject line*.

What would one recommend, and why?

[Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) seems quite tempting, though [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) may be the right thing too.
However sticking to traditional UNIX things is also a good idea (i.e. lex/yacc).

Also I am mostly interested in what would be most suitable for an embedded platform
*(say 200MHz ARM chip running Linux)*.

Comment: I didn't add [Lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) to the list; it might be worth considering.  How much memory would be available on your embedded platform?

Comment: You could start right here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212900/advantages-of-antlr-versus-say-lex-yacc-bison  ;)

Comment: I will have look at lemon then :)

Comment: However, may be with ragel I'd be able to design the entire app, but may be a cumbersome coding practice really..(

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has a list that includes ANTLR, Lemon, Flex, Bison, Ragel, etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212900/advantages-of-antlr-versus-say-lex-yacc-bison similar topic

Answer (score 0):

some opinions:

- [Why you should not use (f)lex, yacc and bison](https://tomassetti.me/why-you-should-not-use-flex-yacc-and-bison/)

  - antlr supports unicode
- [Using byacc+Ragel for memory efficient parsers](https://knzl.at/parser-generators-embedded/)

  - byacc needs less memory
  - (byacc should be replaced with [lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/))