# Is there any bison yacc to ANTLR converter available

Tags: antlr

I have a yacc grammar that I want to convert to ANTLR. Is there any Bison to
ANTLR converter available? Can someone help?

Thanks, 
Prasanth

Comment: An interesting read about the problems with your task is [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212900/advantages-of-antlr-versus-say-lex-yacc-bison).

Comment: @DarkDust Note that the accepted answer of that question is outdated, as ANTLR v4 can handle left-recursion.

Answer (score 5):

Let's compare these parser generators:

- ANTLR v4 is an *ALL(*)* parser generator, a variant of [*LL(*)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)
- Yacc is a [*LALR*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser) parser generator.
- Bison is a [*LALR*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser)/[*GLR*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser) parser generator.

*LL* and *LALR* are [incompatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser#LL_parsers):

> The LALR(k) parsers are incomparable with LL(k) parsers: for any j and k both greater than 0, there are LALR(j) grammars that are not LL(k) grammars and conversely. In fact, it is undecidable whether a given LL(1) grammar is LALR(k) for any k > 0.

*GLR* is a variant of *LR*. An *LR* parser is a bottop-up parser, while an *LL* parser is a top-down parser. Those are fundamentally different parsing strategies.

Conclusion: you won't find any reliable automatic converter any time soon.

Comment: Your answer is basically correct, yet Google turns up this: https://github.com/dowlingw/bison-antlr (whether it's reliable is another matter; and due to LL's inability to cope with left-recursion the grammar to parse needs to be modified first).

Comment: Interesting. But it looks like it's been made for ANTLR v2, which is pretty old now.